# A barra de busca está em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Tanto aqui no site quanto no aqui no Meta.

O campo de busca está com o placeholder "Search...".

[image]

Comment: Será que eles usam alguma dica de linguagem do navegador para tomar a decisão de qual mensagem por? Ou hardcodaram isso e esqueceram das comunidades além das anglófonas?

Comment: Aqui estou utilizando o Safari no macOS 10.13 em pt-BR.

Comment: Não vejo isso como um bug, pois não afeta a pesquisa.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado no SO russo a barra deles está na língua deles

Comment: @Articuno bug de tradução

Comment: Deixaram o `placeholder` não traduzido. Olhem ao inspecionar : `<input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search…"`. Suspeito que tenha sido lapso. É interessante no entanto que a procura de usuários/tags nem sequer term `placeholder`.

Comment: Não é um bug de tradução (eu acho). A barra já havia sido traduzida, entretanto, uma [nova barra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live) está sendo (já foi divulgada, está sendo testada em alguns sites) usada. Então a possível explicação é que estão usando um código fonte em inglês e ainda não fizeram a conexão da barra ao transifex para nós os serelepes e intrépidos programadores em português.

Comment: The string is in transifex and has been for a while - I can only assume it has not been translated there yet.

Comment: @Oded I can clearly remember that the search bar was translated in portuguese, in meta and in the main site. But I will check again in transifex so it can be translated.

Comment: @Stormwind - are you sure? That's `Search…`, not `Search...` (the first uses an ellipsis, the second three dots)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string foi alterada e adicionada à produção. Falta só esperar pela actualização, mas deverão ver a tradução correcta dentro de umas horas, no mínimo. Obrigado!

Comment: Para mim foi resolvido.